# Create a distance matrix from individual distances

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary, matrix

I have a list of distance increase between every two adjacent stations in a railroad in the right order. What I need to do is to create a matrix for the distances between every two stations. This is this list.

```
    +-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
    |    Departure Station    |     Arrival Station     | distance in m |
    +-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
    |                         | San Francisco           |           0.0 |
    | San Francisco           | 22nd Street             |   2521.949349 |
    | 22nd Street             | Bayshore                |     5875.8986 |
    | Bayshore                | South San Francisco     |   6690.161279 |
    | South San Francisco     | San Bruno               |   2964.853585 |
    | San Bruno               | Millbrae Transit Center |   4154.792069 |
    | Millbrae Transit Center | Broadway                |   2549.171972 |
    | Broadway                | Burlingame              |   1762.653178 |
    | Burlingame              | San Mateo               |   2307.847611 |
    | San Mateo               | Hayward Park            |   2148.992125 |
    | Hayward Park            | Hillsdale               |   2597.932334 |
    | Hillsdale               | Belmont                 |       2092.15 |
    | Belmont                 | San Carlos              |   1990.239598 |
    | San Carlos              | Redwood City            |   3492.618122 |
    | Redwood City            | Atherton                |   3847.644532 |
    | Atherton                | Menlo Park              |    1752.92218 |
    | Menlo Park              | Palo Alto               |   2011.382315 |
    | Palo Alto               | Stanford                |   1582.663905 |
    | Stanford                | California Ave.         |       965.606 |
    | California Ave.         | San Antonio             |   3939.685111 |
    | San Antonio             | Mountain View           |   3108.414275 |
    | Mountain View           | Sunnyvale               |    4312.51742 |
    | Sunnyvale               | Lawrence                |   3189.943773 |
    | Lawrence                | Santa Clara             |   5889.680131 |
    | Santa Clara             | College Park            |    2252.43061 |
    | College Park            | San Jose Diridon        |   1872.857195 |
    | San Jose Diridon        | Tamien                  |   2887.967478 |
    | Tamien                  | Capitol                 |    4999.21158 |
    | Capitol                 | Blossom Hill            |   5304.202424 |
    | Blossom Hill            | Morgan Hill             |   19050.76536 |
    | Morgan Hill             | San Martin              |     5917.5495 |
    | San Martin              | Gilroy                  |   10061.59472 |
    | Gilroy                  | Gilroy                  |           0.0 |
    +-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------+
```

My idea was to make a list of distances and a dictionary of stations and their indexes to make a matrix where the values will be generated by looking at the dictionary of stations and defining the range of indexes in which we need to summarize the distances. I worked a lot on making this matrix this way but could not obtain the results.

```
import pandas as pd
file = open('/Users/miss_evgenia/Downloads/Caltrain Metrics - Sheet4.csv')
dist = pd.read_csv(file)
distances = list(dist['distance in m'])
#%%
names = list(dist['Departure Station'])
names.pop(0)
names= dict(zip(names, range(len(names))))
#%%
def sumRange(L,a,b):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(a,b+1,1):
        sum += L[i]
    return sum
```

This is the dictionary and list I have.

```
{'San Francisco': 0, '22nd Street': 1, 'Bayshore': 2, 'South San Francisco': 3, 'San Bruno': 4, 'Millbrae Transit Center': 5, 'Broadway': 6, 'Burlingame': 7, 'San Mateo': 8, 'Hayward Park': 9, 'Hillsdale': 10, 'Belmont': 11, 'San Carlos': 12, 'Redwood City': 13, 'Atherton': 14, 'Menlo Park': 15, 'Palo Alto': 16, 'Stanford': 17, 'California Ave.': 18, 'San Antonio': 19, 'Mountain View': 20, 'Sunnyvale': 21, 'Lawrence': 22, 'Santa Clara': 23, 'College Park': 24, 'San Jose Diridon': 25, 'Tamien': 26, 'Capitol': 27, 'Blossom Hill': 28, 'Morgan Hill': 29, 'San Martin': 30, 'Gilroy': 31}

[0.0, 2521.949349, 5875.8986, 6690.161279, 2964.8535850000003, 4154.792069, 2549.171972, 1762.653178, 2307.847611, 2148.992125, 2597.932334, 2092.15, 1990.2395980000001, 3492.618122, 3847.6445320000003, 1752.92218, 2011.3823149999998, 1582.663905, 965.6060000000001, 3939.685111, 3108.414275, 4312.51742, 3189.943773, 5889.680131, 2252.4306100000003, 1872.8571949999998, 2887.967478, 4999.21158, 5304.202424, 19050.765359999998, 5917.5495, 10061.594720000001, 0.0]
```

Help, please! Thank you.

Comment: I would transform the list to get the cumulative distance for each station from San Francisco, then you know that the distance between any two stations is the difference between both their distances from San Francisco. I will try to write that up for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to a_guest you might also try the following to get the result back as a pandas dataframe with labels

```
def transform_dataframe():
    with open("test_data.csv", "r") as input_data:
        station_distances = pd.read_csv(input_data)
        # to stop gilroy appearing twice
        station_distances.drop(station_distances.tail(1).index,inplace=True)
    cumulative_distances = station_distances['distance in m'].cumsum()

    distance_matrix = cumulative_distances.values - cumulative_distances.values[:, None]
    distance_matrix = pd.DataFrame(distance_matrix, index=station_distances["Arrival Station"], columns=station_distances["Arrival Station"])
    return distance_matrix
```

Answer (score 7):

You can compute the "positions" of the stations as the `cumsum` of distances and then use [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) for computing the distances:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

positions = data['distance in m'].cumsum()
matrix = squareform(pdist(positions.to_numpy()[:, None], 'euclidean'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the station are the same in departure and arrival, maybe you can try something like this:

```
cities = np.unique(distance_table["Departure Station"])
matrix = pd.DataFrame(columns = cities, index = cities)
for j in distance_table:
    matrix.at[distance_matrix.iloc[j,0],distance_matrix.iloc[j,1]] = distance_matrix.iloc[j,2]
```

Where distance_table is the one you show in your question. Maybe you can even do it with a .apply()